# Other ways of subreferencing images?

Tags: java, image, awt

The only way I've found of drawing part of an image is with this `drawImage` function:

public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,int dx1,int dy1,int dx2,int dy2,int sx1,int sy1,int sx2,int sy2,ImageObserver observer)

**Is there a way of drawing a section of an image which only requires destination coordinates rather than a rectangle?** I want to specify my image cut and then draw it at a coordinate rather than having to worry that the destination rectangle matches the size of my cut. I find this has more room for error as if you get it wrong it squeezes/stretches your image to fit etc. Plus when you have images moving around on screen it means moving two sets of points rather than one simple top left coordinate point.

(I'm sure I've seen a video where someone does this I just can't remember what the function is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a sub-image from your Image and then draw that.

Please check out the [BufferedImage API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), the `getSubImage()` method. This will return a cut out image from the big image as a BufferedImage object. Then you can draw this with a simpler `drawImage(...)` overload that just takes the position.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SubImageEg extends JPanel {
   // images from Wikimedia Commons
   // http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
   public static final String MAIN_IMG_PATH = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/" +
        "thumb/4/43/Sarcophilus_harrisii_taranna.jpg/800px-Sarcophilus_harrisii_taranna.jpg";
   public static final String SECOND_IMG_PATH = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/" +
        "thumb/f/f8/Soldering_a_0805.jpg/800px-Soldering_a_0805.jpg";
   public static final String[] IMAGE_PATHS = {MAIN_IMG_PATH, SECOND_IMG_PATH};
   private static final int SUB_X = 520;
   private static final int SUB_Y = 340;
   private static final int SUB_W = 150;
   private static final int SUB_H = 150;
   private static final int SEC_SUB_X = 400;
   private static final int SEC_SUB_Y = 200;

   private BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[IMAGE_PATHS.length];
   private BufferedImage secondImgSubImg;

   public SubImageEg() {
      try {
         for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_PATHS.length; i++) {
            images[i] = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_PATHS[i]));
         }

         secondImgSubImg = images[1].getSubimage(SUB_X, SUB_Y, SUB_W, SUB_H);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (images[0] != null) {
         g.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0, this);
      }
      if (secondImgSubImg != null) {
         g.drawImage(secondImgSubImg, SEC_SUB_X, SEC_SUB_Y, this);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (images[0] != null) {
         return new Dimension(images[0].getWidth(), images[0].getHeight());
      } else {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SubImageEg mainPanel = new SubImageEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SubImageEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```